# Is it possible to change only AMT using UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring

This question has been posted elsewhere however I have not found a specific answer yet.

What I want to do is simply change the amount (AMT) of a PayPal recurring payments profile from say £55.00 to £60.00. The amount is all I want to change. I am using the below to do this:

```
$request_params = array
                    (
                    'USER'                              => $api_username,
                    'PWD'                               => $api_password,
                    'SIGNATURE'                         => $api_signature,
                    'VERSION'                           => $api_version,
                    'METHOD'                            => 'UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
                    'PROFILEID'                         => 'I-R159ACHCUJHF',
                    'AMT'                       => '60.00',
                    'NOTE'                              => 'Re-adjust amount to £60'
                    );
```

OR

&USER=xxxxxxx&PWD=123456789&SIGNATURE=xyxyxyxyxyxyx&VERSION=85.0&METHOD=UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile&PROFILEID=I-R159ACHCUJHF&AMT=11.00&NOTE=Re-adjust+amount+to+%C2%A360&TAXAMT=0.00

So I guess my question is can this be done using the fields above only or do you know if I am missing some other variables that are required possibly?

On another note, when I run this on the sandbox I get the following error:

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-11-28T10:11:36Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 9a5452736a159
    [ACK] => Failure
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Timeout processing request
)
```

Does anyone understand what this means and if it relates to the way I am requesting the change in amount (AMT) in the params above?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to see a sample of the raw request that you're sending to PayPal.

Comment: Added as an edit. Thanks

Comment: Error code 10001 "Internal Error" is just that: PayPal had an internal problem processing your transaction, and the long message indicates that some PayPal service probably timed out attempting to process it. Apologies on behalf of my former company for the bad error message. It is quite likely that some mistake in your request sent PayPal's code off the rails internally but this does not help you find & fix it. I would submit this to the PayPal integration team as a bug report/request for help. They can trace the issue, tell you what happened, & then fix their bug and/or error messaging :).

Comment: I have also tried adding the CURRENCYCODE but this returns the same result!!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the example I'm cribbing from, you also need to pass CURRENCYCODE. The only example I could actually find was on PayPal Developer Brazil:

https://www.paypal-brasil.com.br/desenvolvedores/code-sample/recurring-payments-php/